# React, prevent invoking function when setting the function inside another function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and want help with not invoking a function inside another function when setting it.

How can I prevent "firstModalButtonFunction" being called when function "handleClick" is invoked?

I am just setting the "firstModalButtonFunction" function inside "handleClick", why is it being invoked.

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from '../components/Modal';

function Contact() {

    // use dynamic model
    // modal content
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [typeModal, setTypeModal] = useState('');
    const [gridColumnModal, setGridColumnModal] = useState(1);
    const [titleModal, setTitleModal] = useState('');
    const [descriptionModal, setDescriptionModal] = useState('');
    const [firstButtonModal, setFirstButtonModal] = useState('');

    // set dynamic modal handle functions
    const [firstModalButtonFunction, setFirstModalButtonFunction] =
        useState(null);

    // handle click method
    const handleClick = () => {
        // set modal
        setOpen(true);

        // handle modal click
        setFirstModalButtonFunction(() => {
            console.log('fn ran');

            // set modal
            setOpen(true);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-center text-3xl font-bold leading-8 tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">
                Contact
            </h1>
            <button
                onClick={handleClick}
                className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                Click me
            </button>


            {/* modal - start */}
            <Modal
                firstModalButtonFunction={firstModalButtonFunction}
                open={open}
                setOpen={setOpen}
                title='this is my modal title'
            >
                <p className='text-sm text-gray-500'>
                    Children ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti,
                    facere.
                </p>
            </Modal>
            {/* modal - end */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contact
```

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Whats the purpose?

Comment: I want to be able to close the Modal by clicking the function firstModalButtonFunction afterwards.

Comment: But you are setting it once again to `true`. Also this closing action (function) should be just a separate function within the component and passed as a prop to the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the purpose of your code. But due to the pattern where setState((prevState)=> fn()). The function is called rather than storing it. To do so Just make another callback ()=> before it.

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    // set modal
    setOpen(true);

    // handle modal click
    setFirstModalButtonFunction(() => () => {
      console.log("fn ran");

      // set modal
      setOpen(true);
    });
  };
```

If you want to set a function. Refer this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-pine-kkf55j?file=/src/App.js:663-883).